# Restrict IIS site to Windows domain users

Tags: http, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

My workplace (~10 workstations and a server) serves a site via IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2. (It's a MediaWiki wiki, nothing to do with ASP or .NET; and it's HTTP, not HTTPS.)

Users logged onto the Windows domain can visit the site by Intranet URL — OUR_MACHINE_NAME.local — and this works fine. However, the site is also accessible from the wider Internet (if you happen to know or guess the server's IP address), and for security reasons I want to prevent this. Only users logged into our Windows domain should be able to access the site.

I've spent a while experimenting with the Authorization settings in IIS, but nothing seems to have any effect. I also found some HTTP settings under "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security", but am not sure what I would need to change.

Can someone advise please? (Apologies for any wrong assumptions: I'm a programmer and have little experience of network configuration.)

Comment: _"nothing seems to have any effect"_ - how do you determine that?

Comment: "Windows Authentication" looked like the appropriate setting, but after I set it to Enabled, the site was still accessible anonymously from the public Internet.

Comment: _"the site was still accessible anonymously from the public Internet"_ - and how did you determine _that_? Did you disable anonymous auth while enabling Windows Auth? Do note that your browser can silently respond to an NTLM 401.

Comment: Disabling Anonymous Auth and enabling Windows Auth does seem to do the trick. It still prompts for user/pass on the first visit (I had thought it might recognise the domain user's credentials automatically) but that is acceptable. Thanks.